# Difference between unitarily equivalent operators?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Is there any property of the operator on a Hilbert space that we loose when we study a unitarily equivalent operator and prove something about that one instaed?

I cant think of any, to me this looks like the same thing as a change of basis on finite dimension i.e just a new matrix. But maybe therse is a significant difference between changing spaces then just changing basis, and between finite and infinite dimension in this aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the situation is similar in Hilbert spaces of finite and infinite dimension.
A unitary transformation preserves the inner product, so the space is unchanged as a Hilbert space.
Infinite dimensional spaces might look different despite being "equal" (isometric).
There are issues related to contiuty of linear maps in infinite dimensional spaces, but I think that is beside the point.

There typically is no problem if you study a single operator with no other objects of interest.
But if some basis (or way of representing the space) is more suitable than others, then changing the basis can be a nuisance.
And most importantly, you cannot always make several operators nice with the same unitary transformation — just like you cannot simultaneously diagonalize two hermitean matrices unless they commute.

In short, it depends on what you want to know about your operator.
If you want to study it in isolation, then unitary transformations don't usually matter.
If you don't, they might.

Comment: right, things like spectrum donst change but characteriseing invariant subspaces might be a different story?

Comment: @Inepsilonwetrust, spectrum remains the same. Invariant subspaces are transformed by the unitary transformation, so they stay "structurally the same". If you find the subspaces of interest for the transformed operator, you can take the inverse transformation of the subspaces to get what you need.

Comment: but consider Beurlings theorem, there is no way of characteriseing the invarant subspaces in terms of sequences I think, since there is no control on what happens to inner functions when they are transformed in term of the sequences. Anyway I think I got your point the structure is still there but there is no way of expressing it I guess. This depend on flaws of the space tho

Comment: @Inepsilonwetrust, a unitary transformation transforms a subspace problem to an equivalent one. The transformed problem can be easier to solve, but any restrictions like the one you mention will stay the same. For such a problem there is no difference between an operator and a unitarily equivalent one, other than convenience.